# Find rotation that maps 5 points to another 5 points in 3D

Tags: 3d, rotations, rigid-transformation

Suppose I am given five points $v_1,\dots,v_5 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ in 3 dimensions, and five more points $w_1,\dots,w_5 \in \mathbb{R}^3$.  I want to find the rotation that maps $v_1 \mapsto w_1, \dots, v_5 \mapsto w_5$ (if one exists; if there are multiple, I'd like to find all of them).  How can I do this?

By rotation, I mean choosing a center point $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and rotation angles in 3 dimensions, that map each point $v_i$ to its corresponding point $w_i$ when $v_i$ is rotated by those angles around the center $p$.  This would be easy if the center of rotation was fixed at the origin; but when it is free to vary, the problem seems much hairier.

The number "five" is not essential.  I am conjecturing that with five points, such a rotation should be uniquely determined; but I am fine with replacing the number "five" with any other small constant.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is called the "absolute orientation" problem.  See, e.g.,

[Closed-form solution of absolute orientation using quaternions](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/papers/Absolute_Orientation.pdf).  Berthold K.P. Horn.  Journal of the OPtical Society of America, vol 4 no 4, April 1987.

[Least-Squares Rigid Motion Using SVD](http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/svd_rot.pdf).  Olga Sorkine-Hornung and Michael Rabinovich.  Computing, vol 1 no 1, January 16, 2017.

[Least-Squares Estimation of Transformation Parameters Between Two Point Patterns](http://cis.jhu.edu/software/lddmm-similitude/umeyama.pdf).  Shinji Umeyama.  IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, vol 13 no 4, April 1991.

Also, it appears that three points suffice to unique determine a rotation and translation that map $v_1,v_2,v_3$ to $w_1,w_2,w_3$.